# Why are my jQuery Dropdown effects jumpy?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, mouseenter, mouseleave

The jQuery I made for a dropdown navigation I made is very jumpy and not very smooth. Can someone please take a look at the jQuery below and tell me what I can do to modify it and make it as smooth as possible?

Thanks

```
    jQuery.noConflict();

var time = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // mouseenter
    jQuery('ul.scmegamenulist li.scmegamenumain').mouseenter(
        function openmenu() {

            // slideDown / fadeIn / show
            if(<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('megamenu/jquery/enable',Mage::app()->getStore()); ?> == 1){
                var openeffect  = <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('megamenu/jquery/open',Mage::app()->getStore()); ?>;
                var opentime    = <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('megamenu/jquery/opentime',Mage::app()->getStore()); ?>;

                if(openeffect       == 1){
                    jQuery(this).children('div.scmegamenusub').stop(true, true).hide().delay(time).fadeIn(opentime);
                }else if(openeffect == 2){
                    jQuery(this).children('div.scmegamenusub').stop(true, true).hide().delay(time).slideDown(opentime);
                }
                else if(openeffect  == 3){
                    jQuery(this).children('div.scmegamenusub').stop(true, true).hide().show();
                }
                else if(openeffect  == 4){
                    jQuery(this).children('div.scmegamenusub').stop(true, true).hide().delay(time).show(opentime);
                }
            }
        }
    );

    // mouseleave
    jQuery('ul.scmegamenulist li.scmegamenumain').mouseleave(
        function closemenu() {

            // slideUp / fadeOut / hide
            if(<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('megamenu/jquery/enable',Mage::app()->getStore()); ?> == 1){
                var closeeffect = <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('megamenu/jquery/close',Mage::app()->getStore()); ?>;
                var closetime   = <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('megamenu/jquery/opentime',Mage::app()->getStore()); ?>;

                if(closeeffect          == 1){
                    jQuery(this).children('div.scmegamenusub').stop(true, true).show().fadeOut(closetime);
                    time = closetime;
                }else if(closeeffect    == 2){
                    jQuery(this).children('div.scmegamenusub').stop(true, true).show().slideUp(closetime);
                    time = closetime;
                }else if(closeeffect    == 3){
                    jQuery(this).children('div.scmegamenusub').stop(true, true).show().hide();
                    time = 0;
                }else if(closeeffect    == 4){
                    jQuery(this).children('div.scmegamenusub').stop(true, true).show().hide(closetime);
                    time = closetime;
                }
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle to show off this *jumpy* animation?

Comment: As I was setting up the files on my local ready to transfer over to a JSFiddle, I noticed everything was smooth. I think the issue is CSS related. I'll have to see what the issue is in my CSS. Thanks